# Causes for HttpDelete header field 'x-method' missing error

Tags: ajax, http, rest, http-delete

Please help me understand the possible causes of an 'x-method' missing error when using HttpDelete.

There is a Windows 7 user using Chrome 23 but HttpDelete isn't working. This test website http://www.mnot.net/javascript/xmlhttprequest/ reports the following for the "What Methods Are Available?" section:

> DELETE: fail (Test execution problem: expected response header field ('x-method') missing.)

The machine also fails to use DELETE when using a custom web application accessing a REST service using jQuery ajax. It reports a 405 exception for any DELETE requests. The application works fine for other machines with the exact same actions.

Information about what could cause the delete verb to fail under these circumstances is appreciated.